# jQuery возврат к родителю в цепочке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой jQuery код

```
$('.error_fixed').children().eq(0).addClass('alert_error').html('Ошика')
```

Вот я ребенку дал класс 'alert_error', а как мне теперь в этой же цепочке обратиться непосредственно к самому родителю?

Можно конечно так

```
$('.error_fixed').children().eq(0).addClass('alert_error').html('Ошика').parent().css('background', 'red')
```

Но это не вариант

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Но это не вариант

Отчего же? [`parent`](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0) прекрасно справляется.

```js
$('.error_fixed').children().eq(0).addClass('alert_error').html('Ошика').parent().css('background', 'red')
```

```css
.alert_error{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='error_fixed'>
  some
  <div>error</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

По результатам разъяснения в комментариях, было найдено искомое решение: [`end`](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Comment: Работает то работает, просто я где то слышал что есть метод который возвращает к родителю, не помню просто ..

Comment: @user208233, ну `parent` - это он и есть.

Comment: что то связанное с .self() или .back() было. Скажем так, даже не к родителю нужно досутп получить, а к первому элементу цепи, ведь я могу и так написать
$('.error_fixed').children().eq(0).addClass('alert_error').html('Ошика').children().eq(0).html('Текст ребенка , у которого родитель h4').parent().css('background' ,'red'); - это уже будет другой родител

Comment: @Flayter, тогда это: `end`: http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: Точно, оно самое

Comment: а кстати в вашем примере два комментария назад, насколько я понимаю логику jquery, вам надо писать .end().end()